# Error Trying to Seque to Navigation View Controller Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'UINavigationController' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift

Actual error is `Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'UINavigationController' in coercion`

Inside the code for view controller before I segue to my nav. view controller I have the below code in my prepare

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueAfterJoin2") {
       // NOTE! THIS IS TWEAKED with "as UINavigationController"
        var nextViewCont:DashboardNavViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController;

        // PASS VARS FROM THIS VIEW TO NEXT
        nextViewCont.passedPassword_toViewDashboard = passedPassword_toView2
        nextViewCont.passedEmail_toViewDashboard = passedUsername_toView2
        nextViewCont.passedUsername_toViewDashboard = passedEmail_toView2
        nextViewCont.passedFocus_toViewDashboard = selectedFocus

    }
}
```

My nav. view controller class is defined as this: `class DashboardNavViewController: UIViewController {`. Should it be declared as something else?

Comment: Why you need to convert that to UINavigationController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
var nextViewCont: DashboardNavViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
```

with

```
var nextViewCont = segue.destinationViewController as! DashboardNavViewController
```

And if you want to present `UINavigationController` then your `DashboardNavViewController` must be a subclass of `UINavigationController` which is right now subclass of `UIViewController` so you can not cast it as `UINavigationController` same as your error says.

And your navigation view controller class should defile like shown below:

```
class DashboardNavViewController: UINavigationController {
```